# Char in a single cell

Tags: excel, matlab

```
DataSet='HS31';

xlswrite(soluzioni_filename, DataSet,'NumeroTagli',offset_dataset);
```

But, when I see the `xls` generated, I get `[H]` `[S]` `[3]` `[1]` in different cells instead of `HS31` in a single cell, which is what I am looking for.

Comment: Use a cell instead - `DataSet={'HS31'};` or `{DataSet}` with `xlswrite`

Comment: This is because `DataSet` is now a character array of 4 characters.  You need to encompass it into a single cell like `DataSet={'HS31'}`.  @Divakar: You beat me to it!

Comment: ok, do you know how to cast the old Dataset to a cell?

Comment: @sparkle As Divakar said: `xlswrite(soluzioni_filename,{DataSet},'NumeroTagli',offset_dataset)`. Just add curly braces around `DataSet`

Comment: @Divakar Write the answer so that this question can be "closed"

Comment: `soluzioni` sounds italian to me BTW.

Comment: @Divakar It definitely is Italian :-) Penso che Sparkle sia italiano, ho ragione? :-)

Comment: I thought you speak spanish Luis! :) Italian too!?

Comment: @Divar Yes, I am Spanish. I recently learned some Italian (actually it's rather easy coming from Spanish). And I don't get many chances to practice it :-)

Comment: haha and `SO` provides many such chances! ;) Good skills really!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write to a specific `cell in excel file` , send off the data as a cell array like this -

```
xlswrite(soluzioni_filename, {DataSet},'NumeroTagli',offset_dataset);
```